# Move an image behind the active element

Tags: css

I have a (vertical) list of links.

It could be something like this:

```
<p>
    "2009"
    <a href="#">I got a hamster</a>
    <a href="#">I got another hamster</a>
</p>
<p>
    "2010"
    <a href="#">I got a cat</a>
</p>
<p>
    "2011"
    <a href="#">I got a dog</a>
</p>
<p>
    "2012"
    <a href="#">I got a horse</a>
</p>

<img scr="images/circle.png" />
```

Is it possible to get an image moving behind the links when they are hovered on or clicked on (instead of marking the link with a colorchange, for instance). Only using CSS? With a nicely floating movement.

Answer (score 1):

for onClick you need to have an event listener.

for :hover you can use something like this:

```
@keyframes move {
from { z-index: 0; transform: scale(1); }
to { z-index: 4; transform: scale(2.5); }
}
```

http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/gboJf

or you can use CSS transition:

http://zomigi.com/blog/css3-transitions-and-z-index/